# Adding DNS resolution to network stack in Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, webkit

Can someone please point me to the code that is for DNS prefetching in the Android browser?
I want to be able to add DNS resolutions to the operating system. Is it possible to do this using an Android app or I need to change the source code or kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Static DNS entries are stored in /etc/hosts.  You could change this via an app, as the ad blockers do, but the device would need to be rooted.